# Amazon Alexa Skills Kit Quick Start Tutorial: Echo cant find my custom skill(Ireland Specific)

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

When creating my first skill following the amazon tutorial:

https://developer.amazon.com/alexa-skills-kit/alexa-skill-quick-start-tutorial

I ran into the issue that when testing the skill in the developer console it worked fine but calling the skill from the echo via voice command it was not able to find it. Even though I could see the skill via the alexa app.

Posting this as I found the solution and hoping it could help others.

Answer (score 2):

Basically I found it was down to two issues.

Firstly I re-hosted my lambda skill in Ireland rather than in "US East(N Virginia)" as described in the tutorial in Step 1 - part 3.

Then, after Section 2 - Part 4, after you "Add a new Skill" you need to select English(UK).

After making these changes my device could find my skill. I was getting pretty frustrated before finally finding this solution so hopefully it can help a few others.

Comment: Maybe report it in the official documentation as well?